# Update to gRPC 1.44.0 causes implicit conversion warnings

Tags: firebase, grpc

Using Xcode 13.3.1 with Swift I just updated all my firebase packages and am now seeing 130 warnings for implicit conversion loses integer precision in gRPC-core and gRPC-cpp. (gRPC is at 1.44.0) Does anyone have suggestions on what I might be missing?

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71992740/grpc-core-insane-amount-of-warnings-since-last-update), you might want to ask this question on the GitHub issue tracker or discussion forum for the Firebase SDKs: [firebase-ios-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk)

Comment: Same here, glad it's not just me. Anyone found any solutions or do we just carry on until resolved in a future update?

Comment: Found this, looks like they're on it https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9790